# Providing data through a HOC but when calling component Property '' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '' error appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-components

I have the following HOC component providing firebase to my component:

```
import React from 'react'

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext({})

export const withFirebase = <Props extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
): React.ComponentType<Props> =>
  class WithFirebase extends React.Component<Props> {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
      return (
        <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
          {(firebase): React.ReactNode => (
            <Component {...this.props} firebase={firebase} />
          )}
        </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }

export default FirebaseContext
```

My component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Firebase, { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'


interface FirebaseInterface {
  firebase: Firebase
}

const SignInGoogle: React.FC<FirebaseInterface> = ({ firebase }) => {
//component content
}

export default withFirebase(SignInGoogle)
```

But whenever I call my component in my page I get the following error:
`Property 'firebase' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'FirebaseInterface'` and `SignInEmail.tsx(48, 3): 'firebase' is declared here.` (my component)

Firebase is being provided by my HOC component so how can I get rid of this error? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you actually reduce the properties required in the `withFirebase` HOC but your return type does not reflect that. Try:

```
import React from 'react'

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext({})

export const withFirebase = <Props extends { firebase: Firebase }>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
): React.ComponentType<Omit<Props,'firebase'>> =>
  class WithFirebase extends React.Component<Props> {
    render(): React.ReactNode {
      return (
        <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
          {(firebase): React.ReactNode => (
            <Component {...this.props} firebase={firebase} />
          )}
        </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }

export default FirebaseContext
```

The `Omit` helper requires ts 3.5 but it's also available in the react typings (I think). The point is given a component which requires `firebase` return a component which doesn't

Comment: Thanks for your help! It doesn't work unfortunately the following errors pops up ```Type 'typeof WithFirebase' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Pick<Props, Exclude<keyof Props, "firebase">>>'.``` on   class WithFirebase

Comment: Actually it works I had to just omit it from all the props interfaces! Thank you!